# Android: Notification sound duration

Tags: android, audio, notifications

I'm having some trouble trying to set a duration for my notification alarm sound. Here's how it looks now:

```
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    // mId allows you to update the notification later on.
    mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);

    Uri alarmSound = Uri.parse(sharedPref.getString(
                "notifications_new_message_ringtone", ""));

    if (alarmSound != null) {
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(context, alarmSound);
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {

        }

         mBuilder.setSound(alarmSound);



        mNotificationManager.notify(notificationId, mBuilder.build());

        new Thread() {
            public void run() {

                try {
                    sleep(sharedPref.getInt("alarm_duration",2000) * DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                mNotificationManager.cancel(notificationId);
            }
        }.start();
    }
```

As you can see, I stop the notification after a period of time given by a sharedPref variable (the user can set this up). The thing is that this line: "mNotificationManager.cancel(notificationId)" will not only stop the sound but the whole notification (lights, vibration, and even the icon on the notification drawer).

Is there a way to ONLY shut the notification up without completely cancelling it?

Thanks in advance!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to only cancel the sound. You could cancel the entire `Notification`, then post it again without the sound. Alternatively, you could mute the `AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION` stream type for `x` amount of time, then unmute it after the `Notification` sound has ended.

To control the volume:

```
    setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION);
```

To mute the `Notification` sound:

```
    final AudioManager am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    am.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, true or false);
```

Comment: Thanks! :) I like the first approach. I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: I couldn't implement this:    setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION); because I'm not on an activity (I'm on a broadcast receiver). As regards the second piece of code it doesn't seem to do much :(

Comment: Unfortunately, the method is not static. "ERROR: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method setVolumeControlStream(int) from the type Activity"

Answer (score 0):

Do you know what happens when a notification comes in and you touch the notification bar? It does not cancel the notification, just stops its sound. Seems like there should be a way to do the same from the code.